# Using nodemailer with heroku

Tags: reactjs, email, heroku, next.js, nodemailer

i have a next.js app deployed with heroku https://new-cardenal.herokuapp.com/reserve with a contact form that has a submit button that sends an email and it works fine when i run it locally via: npm install, npm run build, npm start but when i try it on the heroku url it sends a 500 error, here is my code

server.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors')
    const next = require('next');
    const path = require('path');
    const url = require('url');
    const cluster = require('cluster');
    const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
    const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    const mailer = require('./mailer')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    if (!dev && cluster.isMaster) {
      for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.error(`Node cluster worker ${worker.process.pid} exited: code ${code}, signal 
    ${signal}`);
      });
    } else {
    const nextApp = next({ dir: '.', dev });
    const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();
    nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(cors());
    server.use(bodyParser.json())
    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    server.post('/api/contact', (req, res) => {
    const {senderMail,sendTo,rooms,date} = req.body
    mailer({senderMail,sendTo,rooms,date}).then(() => {
    console.log('success')
    res.send('success')
      }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('failed', error)
     res.send('badddd')
    })})
    if (!dev) {
    server.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var proto = req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"];
      if (proto === "https") {
        res.set({'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31557600'});
        return next();
      }
      res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
     });
    }
    server.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static'), {maxAge: dev ? '0' 
     : '365d'}));
    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
    nextHandler(req, res, parsedUrl);
    });
    server.listen(port, (err) => {if (err) throw err;});
   });
    }
```

contact.js

```
    import nodemailer from "nodemailer"
    const emailPass = "qbmD6Zs8Qv76b96"
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "eitanschreiber97@gmail.com",
      pass: emailPass
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }})
    export default async (req, res) => {
    const { senderMail, sendTo, rooms, date } = req.body
    if (sendTo === "" || rooms === "" || date === "") {
    res.status(403).send("")
    return
    }
    const mailerRes = await mailer({ senderMail, sendTo, rooms, date })
    res.send(mailerRes)
    }
    const mailer = ({ senderMail, sendTo, rooms, date }) => {
    const message = {
    senderMail,
    to: `${sendTo}`,
    subject: `El Cardenal Hotel`,
    text: `Thank you for your reservation
    you have reserved rooms: ${rooms} for ${date}
    to cancel you can contact El Cardenal Hotel at (+593) 99 642 4583 or email at 
    elcardenalhotel@gmail.com`,
    replyTo: senderMail
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transporter.sendMail(message, (error, info) =>
        error ? reject(error) : resolve(info)
    )})}
```

reserve.js

```
                    import React, { Component } from 'react'
            import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
            import Link from 'next/link'
            import styled from 'styled-components'
            import Header from '../components/header'
            import OtherFooter from '../components/otherFooter'
            import { sendContactMail } from "../components/networking/mail-api"
            import Rooms from '../data/rooms'
            import moment from 'moment';
            import { GoArrowLeft } from 'react-icons/go';
            import { GoArrowRight } from 'react-icons/go';
            import { i18n, withTranslation } from '../i18n'
            import { createForm, createFactory, createField } from 'micro-form'
            import axios from 'axios';
            const Wrapper=styled.div``
            class DayNames extends Component {
                render() {
                    return (<div className="row day-names">
                        <span className="day">Sun</span>
                        <span className="day">Mon</span>
                        <span className="day">Tue</span>
                        <span className="day">Wed</span>
                        <span className="day">Thu</span>
                        <span className="day">Fri</span>
                        <span className="day">Sat</span>
                      </div>);
                }}
            class Week extends Component {
              render() {
                let days = [];
                let {
                  date,
                } = this.props;
                const {
                  month,
                  selected,
                  select,
                } = this.props;
                for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                  let day = {
                      name: date.format("dd").substring(0, 1),
                      number: date.date(),
                      isCurrentMonth: date.month() === month.month(),
                      isToday: date.isSame(new Date(), "day"),
                      date: date
                  };
                  days.push(<Day day={day}selected={selected}select={select}/>);
                  date = date.clone();
                  date.add(1, "day");
                }
                return <div className="row week" key={days[0]}>{days}</div>;
              }}
            class Day extends Component {
              render() {
                const {
                  day,
                  day: {
                    date,
                    isCurrentMonth,
                    isToday,
                    number
                  },
                  select,
                  selected
                } = this.props;
                return <span key={date.toString()}className={"day" + (isToday ? " today" : 
           "") + (isCurrentMonth ? "" : " different-month") + (date.isSame(selected) ? " 
           selected" : "")}onClick={()=>select(day)}>{number}</span>;
              }}
            const which = [201, 202, 301, 302, 303, 304];
            class ReservePage extends Component {
              constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state={rooms:[false,false,false,false,false,false],
                            em:``,
                          firstMonth: moment(),secondMonth: moment(),firstSelected: 
    moment().startOf('day'),firstShow: false,secondSelected: 
    moment().startOf('day'),secondShow: false,thank_you:false}}
              static async getInitialProps(ctx){
                return {namespacesRequired: ['common', 'header']}
              }
              selectRoom = n => {
                const y = n
                this.setState(prev => {
                  const rooms = prev.rooms.map((r, ind) => {if (ind == y) {return !r
                  } else {return r}})
                  return { rooms }
                })}
                submitForm = async e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  const senderMail = `eitanschreiber97@gmail.com`
                    const res = await sendContactMail(senderMail, this.state.em, 
    which.filter((w, ind) => this.state.rooms[ind]), 
    [this.state.firstSelected.format("ll"),this.state.secondSelected.format("ll")])
                    if (res.status < 300) {
                      this.setState({rooms: [false,false,false,false,false,false],thank_you: 
    true,em: ``,firstSelected: moment().startOf('day'),firstShow: false,secondSelected: 
    moment().startOf('day'),secondShow: false})
                    }
                  }
                  firstPrevious = () => {
                    const {
                      firstMonth,
                    } = this.state;
                    this.setState({firstMonth:firstMonth.subtract(1,'month')});
                  }
                  secondPrevious = () => {
                    const {
                      secondMonth,
                    } = this.state;
                    this.setState({secondMonth:secondMonth.subtract(1,'month')});
                  }
                  firstNext = () => {
                    const {
                      firstMonth,
                    } = this.state;
                    this.setState({firstMonth:firstMonth.add(1,'month')});
                  }
                  secondNext = () => {
                    const {
                      secondMonth,
                    } = this.state;
                    this.setState({secondMonth:secondMonth.add(1,'month')});
                  }
                  firstSelect = day => 
    this.setState({firstShow:true,firstSelected:day.date,firstMonth:day.date.clone()});
                  secondSelect = day => 
    this.setState({secondShow:true,secondSelected:day.date,secondMonth:day.date.clone()});
                  renderFirstWeeks() {
                    let weeks = [];
                    let done = false;
                    let date = this.state.firstMonth.clone().startOf("month").add("w" 
    -1).day("Sunday");
                    let count = 0;
                    let monthIndex = date.month();
                    const {
                      firstSelected,
                      firstMonth,
                    } = this.state;
                    while (!done) {
                      weeks.push(<Week key={date}date={date.clone()}month=. 
  {firstMonth}select={(day)=>this.firstSelect(day)}selected={firstSelected}/>);
                      date.add(1, "w");
                      done = count++ > 2 && monthIndex !== date.month();
                      monthIndex = date.month();
                    }
                    return weeks;
                  };
                  renderSecondWeeks() {
                    let weeks = [];
                    let done = false;
                    let date = this.state.secondMonth.clone().startOf("month").add("w" 
    -1).day("Sunday");
                    let count = 0;
                    let monthIndex = date.month();
                    const {
                      secondSelected,
                      secondMonth,
                    } = this.state;
                    while (!done) {
                      weeks.push(<Week key={date}date={date.clone()}month=. 
          {secondMonth}select={(day)=>this.secondSelect(day)}selected={secondSelected}/>);
                      date.add(1, "w");
                      done = count++ > 2 && monthIndex !== date.month();
                      monthIndex = date.month();
                    }
                    return weeks;
                  };
                  renderFirstMonthLabel() {
                    const {
                      firstMonth,
                    } = this.state;
                    return firstMonth.format("MMMM YYYY");
                  }
                  renderSecondMonthLabel() {
                    const {
                      secondMonth,
                    } = this.state;
                    return secondMonth.format("MMMM YYYY");
                  }
              render() {
                const { rooms, date, em } = this.state
                return (<Wrapper>
                    <Header/>
    <main style={{width:`100%`, margin:0, position:`relative`, top:`7vh`, paddingTop:`90px`, 
    paddingBottom:`90px`, display:`flex`, flexDirection:`column`, alignItems:`center`, 
    zIndex:1, backgroundImage:`url(/roomsPage/background_1.png)`, 
    backgroundPosition:`center`, backgroundSize:`cover`, backgroundRepeat:`no-repeat`}}>
                      <section>
                        <h1>Select your room</h1>
                        <div className="top_list">
                        {Rooms.map((r,ind)=>{
                          return <div onClick={()=>this.selectRoom(ind)}>
                              <h1>{r.number}</h1>
     <div style={{width:`240px`,height:`170px`,background:`center / cover no-repeat 
     url(/roomsPage/${r.number}.jpg)`,backgroundColor:this.state.rooms[ind] ? `grey` : 
     null,backgroundBlendMode:`multiply`}}></div>
                            </div>})}
                          </div>
                          <h1>Select the date</h1>
                          <div className="dates">
                            <div>
                              <p>Check in</p>
                              <section>
     {this.state.firstShow ? <p>{this.state.firstSelected.format("ll")}</p> : null}
                                <section className="calendar">
                                  <header className="header">
                                    <div className="month-display row">. 
   {moment().format("MMMM YYYY") != this.renderFirstMonthLabel() ? <GoArrowLeft onClick=. 
   {this.firstPrevious}/> : null}<span className="month-label">. 
   {this.renderFirstMonthLabel()}</span><GoArrowRight onClick={this.firstNext}/></div>
                                    <DayNames />
                                  </header>
                                  {this.renderFirstWeeks()}
                                </section>
                              </section>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <p>Check out</p>
                              <section>
                                {this.state.secondShow ? <p> 
     {this.state.secondSelected.format("ll")}</p> : null}
                                <section className="calendar">
                                  <header className="header">
                                    <div className="month-display row">. 
         {moment().format("MMMM YYYY") != this.renderSecondMonthLabel() ? <GoArrowLeft 
         onClick={this.SecondPrevious}/> : null}<span className="month-label"> 
         {this.renderSecondMonthLabel()}</span><GoArrowRight onClick={this.secondNext}/> 
         </div>
                                    <DayNames />
                                  </header>
                                  {this.renderSecondWeeks()}
                                </section>
                              </section>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="bottom">
                          <div>
                          <p>Email</p>
                          <input type="text"id="em"name="em_name"value={em}onChange= 
       {e=>this.setState({em:e.target.value})}/>
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" onClick={this.submitForm}>Reserve</button>
                          {this.state.thank_you && <p>thank you</p>}
                          </div>
                      </section>
                    </main>
                    <OtherFooter/>
                  </Wrapper>)}}
            export default withTranslation('common')(ReservePage)
```

mail-api.js

```
           import axios from "axios"
            export const sendContactMail = async (senderMail, sendTo, rooms, date) => {
                const data = {senderMail, sendTo, rooms, date}
                try {
                    const res = await axios({
                        method: "post",
                        url: "/api/contact",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        data
                    })
                    return res
                } catch (error) {
                    return error
                }
            }
```

what do i need to fix

UPDATE: apparently i need to add ajax code

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://new-cardenal.herokuapp.com/',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json;'},
    data: {
    "subject": "the subject",
    "message": "the body"
    },
    }).done(function (res) {
    console.log(res); // it shows your email sent message.
    });
```

i'm just not sure which file to put it code in or do i create a new file

Answer (score -1):

never mind i figured it out i singed in with google accounts and kept the window open then ran: npm install, npm run build and npm start and it worked